# Power Automate - Need help sorting an array based on one field that's a number in string format

Tags: arrays, string, sorting, integer, power-automate

I have an array of data and all values are in string format due to some prior JSON operations in the flow.  I need to sort the array based on one field which are numbers (in string format).  I'm using the sort function and it currently sorts the array, but it's done as a string and sorts 'alphabetically' (e.g. "20", "290", "3", "300", "31" instead of the desired "3", "20", "31", "290", "300")

I've tried using `Int()` and `Float()` to convert the field to an integer.  I'm using the functions wrapped around the mapped item in a select action `int(item()?['Points_Total'])` with no success. See images.

Both functions give the same error:

> The template language function ('int' or 'float') was invoked with a
> parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the
> target type.

The data in the field are whole numbers, both positive and negative. I'd think that both functions could handle the values I'm working with.

Here is how I'm trying to convert the field Points_Total:

[image]

Error and View of Data Field

[image]

Any ideas from the community?

Thank you!

Comment: Are any of the fields `null` that you're trying to convert to a number?

Comment: had to check and there are blank values in the list "Points_Total": ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you have a blank value there somewhere.  You'll need to check for that prior to converting to a numeric value.  Your expression should be changed to something like this ...

```
if(isInt(item()?['Points_Total']), int(item()?['Points_Total']), 0)
```

... my suggestion would be to set it to zero in the cases where it's not a number however, if that skews your results, etc. then you can choose what you do.

Also, I've used `isInt` given you said the numbers are whole.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I tried the expression. The select action succeeded but the compose action that follows it, which sorts the array, failed with the error `The...function 'sort' expects the sortBy parameter ... to reference a parameter that is the same type for each object in the array.`After looking at it I see it did not update the type of the existing string values, but it did replace the blanks with 0 and the replacements are integers (no double quotes around them).

Comment: I wrapped `int()` around your expression and it converted everything correctly. The sort worked great also.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Oh perfect, sorry, I missed that part, duh!  Will update my answer to make it clear for others.